# MySQL Database Optimization - I have a message table with a lot of duplicates

Tags: mysql, optimization, duplicates, message

I have a table in my database for messages. The problem is that I've a row for each messages for each recipient, even though they are receiving the same messages. See below:

```
|  ID  | RECIP_ID  | MESSAGE               |
|  1   | 366       | "URGENT REMINDER..."  |
|  2   | 367       | "URGENT REMINDER..."  |
|  3   | 368       | "URGENT REMINDER..."  |
```

So, as you can (hopefully) see, it's the same message saved against each recipient. I am sure this is horribly inefficient. What's the best way to do this? I want to record what message each recip_id has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a short, I would suggest [to normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables. To store data efficient, it requires you to use at least 3 tables:

- ***Messages***(Id, Content, TimeStamp) - to store messages
- ***Recipients***(Id, etc...) - to store recipients
- ***RecipientMessages***(MessageId, RecipientId) - to store which message addressed to which recipient

***Select*** example, which will get data as you formatting above:

```
SELECT
   `r`.*,
   `m`.*
FROM
   `Messages` as `m`
        INNER JOIN `RecipientMessages` as `rm`
            ON `m`.`Id` = `rm`.`MessageId`
        INNER JOIN `Recipients` as `r`
            ON `rm`.`RecipientId` = `r`.`Id`
```

***Insert*** example, which will give you the idea how to write data:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `Messages`
    (`Id`, `Content`, `TimeStamp`)
VALUES
    (NULL, 'URGENT REMINDER...', NOW());

INSERT INTO `RecipientMessages`
    (`MessageId`, `RecipientId`)
VALUES
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 366),
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 367),
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 368);

COMMIT;
```